# How do I find out which functions are deprecated for specific OpenGL profiles?

Tags: opengl

I would like to get the list of functions that are part of a certain OpenGL profile and the list of the ones that are deprecated so that I can avoid those.

Comment: _I believe_ that when using a deprecated feature, you should see an error when you call `glGetError()`.  If you call `glGetError()` after every `gl*` call, you may be able to root them out that way

Comment: For legacy OpenGL (before version 3), there is a dedicated article: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The true source of this information is in the various [OpenGL specifications](http://www.opengl.org/registry/). They contain a list of what functions there are, what their definitions are, what enumerators those functions take, and so forth. For each OpenGL version.

If you want what was ***removed*** (deprecated means "present but not advised to use". When [something is removed](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts), it is *removed*), the 3.1 spec section E.2.2 has a list of the removed functionality.

However, if you simply want to avoid non-core functions, you should use an [OpenGL loading library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) that has headers that exclude removed functions. [GL3w](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#GL3W) can work in this capacity, but it doesn't load extensions. The only one I know of that does this [is my own](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#Unofficial_OpenGL_SDK) (which is why I wrote it; to get rid of the non-core cruft).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to navigating the registry PDFs.

The quickest/easiest way I have found is to do a search in the raw [gl.spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/gl.spec) file. It's the file from which the other stuff is generated, not designed to be human readable but isn't bad.

Just remove the leading prefixes, gl or GL_ from the name. The entries have a deprecated property as well as adding them to a deprecated category. It also tells you at what version it was introduced so you know when it's been made available.

You could also process them using a simple script to extract the information and put it into a list.

Comment: Or you could just [download these XML files](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gl-xml-specs/downloads), which have the same contents, just in a much more reasonable format.

Answer (score 1):

You have all this information in he [OpenGL Registry](http://www.opengl.org/registry/). There you can check the current OpenGL API, OpenGL Shading Language and GLX Specifications and Reference Pages, as well as the old versions'.

Comment: where is the list exactly?

Comment: Depends on which version you want to look at. [Here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/) you have the Reference for OpenGL 4. [Here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/) the rest of the documentation.